# passing a variable in name attribute in html

Tags: php, html, variables, name-attribute

this code outputs different question from db until while loop expires with MCQ options of type radio:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `type` IN 
    ('".implode("','",$fin_element)."')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<br>";
     echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "<br>";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question1' value='answer1.1'/    >
          <code>".$row["answer1"]."</code>". "<br>";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question1' value='answer1.2'/>
          <code>".$row["answer2"]."</code>". "<br>";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question1' value='answer1.3'/>
          <code>".$row["answer3"]."</code>". "<br>";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question1' value='answer1.4'/>
          <code>".$row["answer4"]."</code>". "<br>";  
    }
    } else {
   echo "0 results";
    }
```

but here every  options of every question have the same **name attribute** of **question1** only , but i want that for the next question name attribute should change to **question2** and so on. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an identifier in your table `question`, you could use it.

But you could just use a variable to increment question number :

```
$index = 1 ;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<br>";
     echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "<br>";

     echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.1'/    >
          <code>".$row["answer1"]."</code>". "<br>";
     //...
     $index++;
 }
```